# Algorithms and the Strategy Design Pattern? Breaking a process into codependent steps

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, constraints

I am designing a factory that creates objects of `Maze` type. The factory requires three distinct steps to create the mazes and one optional step.

1. partition (split) the 2d or 3d closed space into `Partition`s (rooms). This step is called `Partitioning`.
2. Check which `Partition`s' surfaces overlap sufficiently (which rooms share a wall) so that it's possible to (add a door between them and) connect them. This step I call `Graphing`.
3. Run a Spanning Tree or a similar algorithm that connects all `Partition`s as a Tree or a similar connected Graph structure. I call this `Linkning`.
4. Optional*: Create the actual doors between `Partition`s.

I have a class called MazeGenerator that accepts a `Partitioning`(1), `Graphing`(2), `Linking`(3) and possibly a `DoorGeneration`(4) method.

Alright, the issue is with flexibility and usability:

Some methods of spliting the space, are very rigid (for instance spliting it into a grid) and allow us to use a much faster method in step [2], we may not have to do anything actually cause we know exactly which walls are shared by which rooms and can continue to step [3].

On the other hand, some methods for partitioning are very random and require a lot more work on step [2]. I want to allow users (other devs) to apply the fast method when it is viable but to constraint and convey that they need to use another method when they split the space with a more random method.

The issue is, how do I convey or constraint people that use this API?

So far I thought about adding a protected const array to each method step class called `viableNextStep` that lists all the classes that describe possible methods that can be used in conjunction with this method.

So for instance, `PartitionIntoRigidGrid2D` would have

```
Array viableMethods = [SimpleGridGraph2D, findOverlap2D] // Hope that makes sense
```

Comment: How will the first and next steps be selected? Which class will be responsible for the selection?

Comment: Hi @Glenner003 - The MazeFactory (a singleton) will have a setter to let the user configure the maze creation process. There will be two functions, one for changing a specific step and another for selecting all three steps.

`mazeFactory.selectAlgorithms(stepOne, stepTwo, stepThree);` and `mazeFactory.selectPartitioningAlg(stepOne)` ...

Comment: Hi @Zehelvion then your approach with viableNextsStep seems a good one. It can be used both in the user interface and as  verification method in the selectAlgoritms and other algoritm selectors.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of selectAlgorithms(1,2,3) implement a Builder pattern so you can do mazeFactory.addAlg(1).addAlg(2).addAlg(x) ...